# Dell Inspiron 660 won't boot from SD card

Tags: ubuntu, boot, sd-card

I've recently moved and being the smart guy I am, I left my USB drive back at my old house.

I'm trying to use a friend's SD card to reinstall Ubuntu. I set it up exactly the same way as I would my normal USB drive (which I know I can boot from just fine)

`dd if=ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`

Everything went fine, but when I changed the boot order in my BIOS ("USB Device"), it said that nothing was found.

The SD reader is built-in, if that matters, it's not a USB reader.

Summary: How does one get a Dell Inspiron 660 to boot from an SD card?

Comment: We need information on the reader.  If its not a USB device then changing the boot order to boot to USB devices first doesn't make a great deal of sense.

Comment: Try the F12 boot menu, and see if this SDcard reader appears in any of the categories.

Comment: An *external* SD card reader should work, if you have one, but it's probably easier to buy a USB flash device.